# Capturing Integers from Strings in Java

Tags: java, string, integer, java.util.scanner

I'm attempting to capture integers from a user input using `Scanner`. These integers represent coordinates and a radius between 0 and 1000. It's a circle on a 2D plane.

What I *have* to do is to somehow capture these integers separately from **one line**. So, for example, the user inputs

```
5 100 20
```

Therefore, the x-coordinate is 5, the y-coordinate is 100, and the radius is 20.

The user must input all of these values on **the same line**, and I have to somehow capture the values from the program into three different variables.

So, I tried using this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String coordAndRadius = input.nextLine();

int x = coordAndRadius.charAt(0);   //  x-coordinate of ship
int y = coordAndRadius.charAt(2);   //  y-coordinate of ship
int r = coordAndRadius.charAt(4);   //  radius of ship
```

for one-digit characters, as a test. Didn't turn out so well.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the easiest way (not the nicest one) is just split them into array using String methods :

```
public static void filesInFolder(String filename) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String coordAndRadius = input.nextLine();
    String[] array = coordAndRadius.split(" ");

    int x = Integer.valueOf(array[0]);
    int y = Integer.valueOf(array[1]);
    int r = Integer.valueOf(array[2]);
}
```

You can also use nextInt method, which looks like this :

```
public static void filesInFolder(String filename) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] data = new int[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        data[i] = input.nextInt();
    }            
}
```

Your input will be stored in array `data`

Answer (score 3):

Create a string array using `coordAndRadius.split(" ");` and extract the values from each array element.

Answer (score 3):

You must split the input into 3 different string variables, each of which can be parsed separately.  Use the [`split` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to return an array, with each element containing a piece of input.

```
String[] fields = coordAndRadius.split(" ");  // Split by space
```

Then you can parse each piece into an `int` using [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29):

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(fields[0]);
// likewise for y and r
```

Just make sure you have 3 elements in your array before accessing it.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Provide x, y and radius,");
int x = scanner.nextInt();
int y = scanner.nextInt();
int radius = scanner.nextInt();

System.out.println("Your x:"+x+" y: "+y+" radius:"+radius);
```

It will work either you will type in "10 20 24" or "10\n20\n24"  where \n is of course a newline character.

And just in case you would like to know why your approach does not work here is explanation.

```
int x = coordAndRadius.charAt(0);
```

charAt(0) return first character of your string  which then gets implicitly casted into int. Assume your coordAndRadius ="10 20 24". So in this case first char is '1'. So the statement above can be written as:
int x = (int)'1';

Answer (score 1):

Split the values by space

```
String[] values = coordAndRadius.split(" ");
```

Then get each value as int using `Integer.parseInt`:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
int y = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
int radious = Integer.parseInt(values[2]);
```